# Question on Differentiability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g: (0 , \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $g\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) = g(a) - g(b)$. Prove $g'(x) = \frac{g'(1)}{x}$ for all $x \in (a , b)$ if $g$ is differentiable on $(a , b)$.

Ok so I'm confused on how to prove this. I know $g(1) = 0$, but applying the definition of a derivative with $c \in (a , b)$ gives
\begin{align*}
g'(c) &= \lim_{x \to c} \frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x - c} \\
\end{align*}

which is where I get stuck. Obviously $g(x) - g(c) = g\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$ but I don't think that helps much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$g(x) - g(c) = g\left(\frac{x}{c}\right).$$ Taking derivatives with respect to $x$ we get $$g'(x)=\frac 1cg'\left(\frac{x}{c}\right).$$ In particular, writting $x=c$ we get $$g'(c)=\frac 1c g'(1)=\dfrac{g'(1)}{c}.$$